# Does footage of WWI bombing of London by zeppelins exist?

Tags: world-war-one, bombing, london

I remember seeing footage of a zeppelin dropping bombs on London in a documentary on WWI, however I cannot seem to find it on the Internet. Did I dream or does it actually exist?

Comment: Could what you saw have been a recreation, or bits of footage pasted together to make it look like a bombing?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah. Apparently that was indeed [A Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_strategic_bombing_during_World_War_I). No word there on footage of it though.

Comment: Motion picture cameras weren't often used at night and zeppelins were hard to spot. The number of raids that actually reached London was just 9. I would be surprised if one was caught in the act of dropping bombs on the city.

Comment: @Mat You may have seen the silent ***dramatization*** you can find by PeriscopeFilms under the title [*WORLD WAR ONE NEWSREELS ARGONNE OFFENSIVE LONDON ZEPPELIN RAID RUSSIAN FRONT (SILENT) 27924.*](https://youtu.be/WByp3yn_OOI) The zeppelin footage begins at [3:50](https://youtu.be/WByp3yn_OOI?t=230). Note the info section clearly indicates this was a dramatization, not actual footage.

Comment: I suppose only the first raids could have been filmed, before British air defences forced Zeppelins to reach higher in the sky and attack at night. But I suppose my imagination played tricks on me.

Answer (score 2):

There have been a bunch of fictional movies involving zeppelins and other airships.

I once stumbled upon a scene of a zeppelin attack on London on television. It turned out to be from the famous Howard Hughes movie *Hell's Angels* (1930).  And I don't think it was the only fictional movie to depict a zeppelin attack.

So it is possible that a documentary would use images of a zeppelin attack from an old war movie.  And it is possible that newsreels during World War I used special effects to depict zeppelin attacks on London, and the documentary used some of that more or less fake newsreel footage.

Comment: There is a footage of damage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMbd-UYyEd0 Bombing was performed during nights (because Zeppelins are easy to shoot down), and technology of that time did not permit filming of Zeppelins themselves.

Comment: @Alex That link seems to be to a 1936 Nuremberg rally rather than to WWI Zeppelin  bomb damage